# UITableView crashes my app

Tags: ios, uitableview

it crashes on the line

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];
```

heres the code for my data source(left the containing view controller as data source, by default)

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{


    return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"albumCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"display cell";
    return cell;
}
```

and a link to a print screen of the cell
http://img526.imageshack.us/img526/495/screenshot20121121at115.png

i did the apple example app on uitables and it works, and i cant find the difference between what i did there and what i did here. tried debugging a hundred times. can someone help me figure out the problem with my code?

edit: erased a code that was left from what i commented out

edit 2: i erased the view and put it again and it worked, guess i messed up something in the preferences

Comment: you have an error in this line ``]objectForKey:@"name"];``, maybe it is a mistype

Comment: ]objectForKey:@"name"]; is strange your compiler is not giving error ??

Comment: did you add the identifier to storyboard cell ?

Comment: the object for key is a typo, accidentally pasted some of my comments. and i did add the identifier as seen in the print screen of the cell

Answer (score 0):

```
]objectForKey:@"name"];
```

What is the use of this line? Are you sure you pasted the whole complete code?

Also check your .xib file, in your table view you should type a CellIdentifier field value

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.